# How to use Angular Live Sever with an access token

Tags: angular, authentication, server, localhost, client

Forgive me since I'm a noob but I'm working on a project at work and we are using access tokens to authenticate user but because of that I can't use the live server. I have to manually pass the access token every time i make the change by hitting the url localhost:4200/access_token='token'

everytime the auto refresh hits, I'm taken back to my hosted dev environment

There has to be a better way to pass the token so I can actually take benefit of the live server. Please help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.